# RTSP video streaming for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, rtsp

I want to display on the iPhone screen video stream `RTSP`. Can throw the source code of the project or details on how to implement it. Found 2 project, but they have not compiled:

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RTSPPlay

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RtspFrames-test

Source code from the site `VLC` also does not compile, no files.
Tell me, is it possible to record the stream to a video file? And how is it implemented?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Implementation details are far beyond the scope of this site. I suggest you reference RFC/Literature on RTP streaming. RTSP is only a text based session setup protocol. All media will be transported over RTP. You will also need to look at RTCP packets for lip sync. For an 'easy' solution take a look at the DropCam source code on github.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) for displaying RTSP video stream.
As example you can look at my [project](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) hosted on github.
It's movie player for iOS using ffmpeg and OpenGLES.

Comment: i am not able to compile your code, some lib- files are missing

Comment: i have the same issue, some libs are missing...

Comment: Is there some problems with the file .gitmodule?
I failed to perform the git command..

Comment: I've successfully built your project. However some library must be copied/moved manually. e.g., Pods.a.
I'm not familiar with iOS programming, is there good way to make this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

For me appears that the best choice is 
https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer

Yes, it's pretty old and it won't work out of the box, but if you'll update mpeg libraries to 3.0, refactor project to ARC and get rid of deprecated mpeg methods, it seems to be a good choice. Definitely better than VLC.

All above can be found here https://github.com/rozum-dev/DFURTSPPlayer

Comment: RTSP url not playing with the tutorial