# How to create RTMP/RTSP player using FFMpeg for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, xcode6, http-live-streaming

I am working on an app using RTMP/RTSP links to broadcast/play live audio/video.As iOS devices support HTTP , but my requirement is to play RTMP/RTSP Links.
I want to create my custom player using FFMpeg framework.I have searched over internet , ried many solutions but did not find any solution.

Comment: DFURTSPPlayer project is working http://stackoverflow.com/a/37219951/5490090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a Xcode project based on ffmpeg. It's possible to play RTSP links. Have a look at it:
https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer

If you want to know more about RTSP, I can highly recommend you the following link:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326

Comment: DFURTSPPlayer Fails if to play only audio streams.Well i have have dome rtsp streams playing using gstreamer

Comment: DFURTSPPlayer hasn't been updated in nearly two years.  Are there any currently active projects to assist with RTMP streaming?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an overview of current solutions for rtsp on iOS:
https://gist.github.com/oc2pcoj/e55795550984d205d109
I use ijkplayer at current project for playing video stream from IP-cam. It works fine.

Comment: No. ijkplayer has solutions for both platform. But Github Gist describes solution only for iOS.

Comment: Thank you soo much! finally! this is an rtmp player 'out of the box', easy to setup with the instructions and it's not a paid version or trial!

Comment: anyone here faced problem: It stopped play after some minute. And I need restart.

Answer (score 0):

To play an rtsp stream on iOS using ffmpeg I recommend https://github.com/teocci/RTSP-Client-iOS

For reference, here is an Objective-C interface to `RTSP-Client-iOS/FFMpegDecoder/RTSPPlayer.m` based on `RTSP-Client-iOS/RtspClient/ViewController.swift`;

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewInstance1;

@end


//
//  ViewController.m
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RTSPPlayer.h"

RTSPPlayer *rtspPlayer;
int frameIndex;
NSTimer *timerRefresh;

#define CAMERA_RTSP_ADDRESS "rtsp://..."
#define CAMERA_FPS (30.0)
#define TIMER_INTERVAL_SECONDS (1.0/CAMERA_FPS)


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* address = @CAMERA_RTSP_ADDRESS;
    rtspPlayer = [[RTSPPlayer alloc] initWithVideo:address usesTcp:false];
    rtspPlayer.outputWidth = 640;
    rtspPlayer.outputHeight = 480;
    [rtspPlayer seekTime:0.0];

    timerRefresh = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL_SECONDS target:self selector:@selector(run:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) run:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    if(![rtspPlayer stepFrame])
    {
        [timerRefresh invalidate];
        [rtspPlayer closeAudio];
    }

    UIImage* uiImage = rtspPlayer.currentImage;

    _imageViewInstance1.image = uiImage;

    frameIndex++;
}

@end
```

<sub>To create an ImageView object in the user interface (_imageViewInstance1);</sub>

- <sub>Project Navigator (left pane) - [INSERTAPPLICATIONNAME]</sub>
- <sub>Open Main.storyboard</sub>
- <sub>Select View Controller Scene - View Controller - View</sub>
- <sub>Select the Library button (top right: circle with inside square)</sub>
- <sub>Search for 'Image View'</sub>
- <sub>Drag and drop a new View Image Object into View Controller Scene - View Controller - View (adjacent 'Safe Area')</sub>
- <sub>Create an outlet connection for the new Image View object</sub>
- <sub>Select the Assistant Editor button (top right: two intersecting circles)</sub>
- <sub>Select file ViewController.h in the Project Navigator</sub>
- <sub>If necessary hide the left and right panes to create more space (top right: blue box with left vertical bar, blue box with right vertical bar)</sub>
- <sub>hold the Ctrl key and drag the new image view object to the ViewController.h file (immediately below @interface ViewController: UIViewController) - name the object reference as imageViewInstance1</sub>